# Function parameters and arguments

Tags: javascript

Here I have a function called displayMenuItems. I'm struggling to understand function parameters and arguments. I don't understand why this function has to have the parameter (menuItems). menuItems doesn't appear anywhere else in my code and has no values assigned to it, so why do I have to put it there? I just can't get my head around it. To me it seems pointless having it there.

```js
function displayMenuItems(menuItems) {
    let displayMenu = menuItems.map(function(item) {
        return `<article class="menu-item">
        <img src=${item.img}  class='photo' alt=${item.title}>
        <div class="item-info">
         <header>
            <h4>${item.title}</h4>
            <h4 class="price">${item.price}</h4>
         </header>
         <p class="item-text">
         ${item.desc}
         </p>
        </div>
      </article>`;
    });
    displayMenu = displayMenu.join('');
    sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
}
```

Comment: `menuItems` is used in the first line `menuItems.map` see [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It's there so the caller of `displayMenuItems()` can define what the content of `sectionCenter` should be

Comment: So are you saying (menuItems) is being declared as the name of the array that's going to be created within the function with .map?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the code within the function exists in another context than the outside world. See this example:

```js
// within the function the first and second parameter 
// are named x and y respectively
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y; 
}

// but outside, we can use any name we like
const foo = 2;
const bar = 3;

console.log(add(foo, bar));

// it does not even need to be variables
console.log(add(3, 4));

// instead of using position based parameters
// we can also simulate named parameters by
// using an object as the only parameter.
function subtract({ x, y }) {
  return x - y;
}

// the above is a shorthand for
//function subtract(args) {
//  return args.x - args.y;
//}

// no we need to use the "names" x and y when
// setting the parameters
console.log(subtract({ x: 5, y: 2 }))
```

Comment: So how does it know x is 2 and y is 3? It doesn't make sense to me. menuItems is not anywhere else outside of the function. What's linked to it?

Comment: @Anon2945 because of the order of the arguments. The first argument given to `add` will be available as `x` within the function.

Comment: I'm still confused. I fully understand everything else that's going on but I can't get my head around this. In my example is the argument (menuItems) there because I'm creating an array with .map?

Comment: No. `map` is a function provided by arrays. If you would call `displayMenuItems(1)` with for example the number 1, you would get an error, as a Number does not provide a map function (you cannot do this: `1.map()`), but you can do this `[1,2].map(v => v + 1)` which would return `[2,3]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of menu items called `menu`, you must pass them to the function. The function refers to `menu` as `menuItems` internally. Both `menu` and `menuItems` are the same. They both share the same memory address. Additionally, `menuItems` is a required parameter and must be an array of objects. The `item` is the current item in the array your passed in.

All `item` objects are required to have the properties: `title`, `desc`, `price`, and `img`.

The `sectionCenter` variable is defined outside the function (globally scoped), so you must know the element ahead of the function call.

The `displayMenu` variable is a variable that holds your concatenated HTML string. It is the output of the mapping/joining of each item processed by the template-literal expression.

```js
const sectionCenter = document.querySelector('.section-center');

const menu = [{
  title: 'Apple',
  desc: 'A red fruit',
  price: 1.00,
  img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/128/F00/FFF?text=Apple'
}, {
  title: 'Banana',
  desc: 'A yellow fruit',
  price: 2.00,
  img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/128/FF0/000?text=Banana'
}, {
  title: 'Orange',
  desc: 'An orange fruit',
  price: 1.50,
  img: 'https://via.placeholder.com/128/F70/FFF?text=Orange'
}];

// Pass a reference of `menu` to the function.
// It will be referred to as `menuItems` inside the function.
displayMenuItems(menu);

function displayMenuItems(menuItems) {
  let displayMenu = menuItems.map(function(item) {
    return `
      <article class="menu-item">
        <img src=${item.img}  class='photo' alt=${item.title}>
        <div class="item-info">
         <header>
            <h4>${item.title}</h4>
            <h4 class="price">$${item.price.toFixed(2)}</h4>
         </header>
         <p class="item-text">
         ${item.desc}
         </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    `;
  });
  displayMenu = displayMenu.join('');
  sectionCenter.innerHTML = displayMenu;
}
```

```css
.section-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-center .menu-item {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-center"></section>
```

Comment: Are you saying that (menuItems) is there because of the array being created by .map within the function? So essentially I'm passing the name of the array as a parameter before creating it in the function?

Comment: @Anon2945 You are passing an array of objects to the function. The function refers (locally) to those outside items as `menuItems`. The array is passed by reference into the function. The array you passed in is being transformed into a new array. It's a one-to-one ratio. If the source array has 10 items, the mapped array will also contain 10 items.

Comment: OK so my source array in my code is called menu. If in my function I've given the argument (menuItems), how does it know I'm refering to my source array which is called menu? Why wouldn't I just pass menu as an argument?

Comment: @Anon2945 when you pass the variable `menu` into the function, it refers to that variable (internally) as `menuItems`. It is just an alias that let's the function know that it was passed in, rather than accessed globally.

Comment: const menu = [
 {
  id: 1,
  title: 'buttermilk pancakes',
  category: 'breakfast',
  price: 15.99,
  img: './images/item-1.jpeg',
  desc: `I'm baby woke mlkshk wolf bitters live-edge blue bottle, hammock freegan copper mug whatever cold-pressed `
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  title: 'diner double',
  category: 'lunch',
  price: 13.99,
  img: './images/item-2.jpeg',
  desc: `vaporware iPhone mumblecore selvage raw denim slow-carb leggings gochujang helvetica man braid jianbing. Marfa thundercats `
 },

Comment: @Anon2945 I updated my code to show the assignment of the array to `menu` outside of the function. I also added more explanation in terms of references and memory addresses.

Comment: I still don't get how it links menuItems to menu. What happens if menu isn't the only one? What's saying that menuItems is an alias for menu?

Comment: @Anon2945 Because the position of the parameters matter. I could pass in a variable called `dog` and it would still be referred to as `menuItems`, because that is how functions identify the first parameter. Furthermore, `arguments[0] === menuItems === menu`. This is foundational knowledge in any programming language; at least the ones that pass-by-reference. For more info read this, [_"Pass by value vs. pass by reference"_](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference). It's the first result after searching "pass by reference." Looks like it's language-agnostic insight.

Comment: I can't get my head around it. This is the only thing I can't understand. It doesn't seem logical to me. There's nothing saying menu = menuItems. Or is it because this is the only array above the function? I'm completely lost with it.

Comment: @Anon2945 unless you are passing a primitive type to a function/method, the thing being passed in is simply a reference. You cannot change that reference, but you can modify anything that object itself refers to. Object and Array datatypes cannot be reassigned inside a function, but you can change the keys and indices of the internal structure. It offers re-usability and  it one of the main goals of functional and OOP languages.

Comment: @Anon2945 If you still don't understand check out, [_"Describe pass by value and pass by reference in JavaScript?"_](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/describe-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript). I cannot assist you further, because you will have to learn this concept on your own.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Only question I have now is what happens if you have 2 objects/arrays and you want to pass by reference only one of them?

Comment: You always pass objects by reference. You cannot dereference then like you can in native C. You have to be responsible not to alter the object inside the function. JavaScript is the Wild West.

Comment: Yeah but say I have one object called blue and another object called red. Then I create a function that passes by reference (dog) - How does it know which object (blue or red) to reference?